# 4.4 Proposition of Chapter 8 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry

When I read the 4.4 Proposition of Chapter 8 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, I can't understand the red line in picture below. I think the $e$ is identity mapping.  But, obviously, $\gamma$ has a eigenvalue equal to 1   do not means that $\gamma$ is identity mapping. How to understand it ?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recall that $\Gamma$ acts in a **totally discontinuous manner** on $S^n$, for every $x \in S^n$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $g(U) \cap U =\emptyset$, for all $g \in \Gamma \setminus \{e\}$. Now, let $\gamma$ as in the proof that you are studying. So far, we have that there exists $p \in S^n$ such that $\gamma(p)=p$. Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $p$. Then $\gamma(U) \cap U \supset \{p\} \neq \emptyset$. Since $\Gamma$ acts in a totaly discontinuous manner on $S^n$, $\gamma$ have to be the identity in order to no obtain a contradiction.